# How to monitor VMs and its resources under google cloud (GCP)

Tags: monitoring, scripting, google-cloud-platform, google-stackdriver

I have couple of VMs created on Google cloud platform and deployed tomcat based applications. Now, I would like to monitor the resources (like Memory , CPU, disk , applications etc). Is there any way that I could do this through GCP? an event of failure, a notification should be sent to our email addresses. I am thinking of creating a shell script but again it will be like a reinventing the wheel.

I would like to see what are my options here? If the VM is crashed itself or in a shutdown state, I want to receive a notification on that as well.

Thanks
Shankar

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Stackdriver Monitoring](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/quickstart-lamp) for system resources such as memory, CPU and disk space. You can configure an [alerting policy](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/alerts/) for certain metric thresholds and Uptime checks which can notify you by email that an event has occurred. The basic tier, which is free, should provide you all the necessary tools to monitor your GCP VMs. You may want to [compare the basic and premium tier packages](https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/pricing#service_tiers) to decide which is best for you